# trying to convert data from Domino Access Service to a JSON string via JSON.stringify

Tags: json, local-storage, xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

I want to store the result from a call to a Domino Access Service (DAS) in a localStorage however when I try to convert the result object to a JSON string I get an error.

With DAS you get the result as an Array e.g.:

```
[
  {
      "@entryid":"1-CD90722966A36D758025725800726168",
      "@noteid":"16B46",
```

Does anyone know how I get rid of the square brackets or convert the Array quickly to a JSON object?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
var REST = "./myREST.xsp/notesView"; 
$.getJSON(REST,function(data){
    if(localStorage){
        localStorage.setItem('myCatalog',JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

Comment: JSON arrays are represented with square brackets, so the object is in position zero. Try to read the object from the array position zero.

Comment: @Rami: how should I do that?

Comment: I did not test this but I assume the data is the JSON array so data[0] should do the trick.

Comment: Your REST URL var specifies an XPage path, making it not truly DDS(/DAS), but rather an _xe:restService_ with "notesView" as the _pathInfo_ property. Please include that code for easier review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brackets are part of the JSON syntax. They indicate that this is an array of objects. And as you point to a view it is very likely that you would get more than one object back (one for each entry in the view).

So if you are only interested in the first element you could do this:

```
var REST = "./myREST.xsp/notesView"; 
$.getJSON(REST,function(data){
    if(localStorage){
        var firstRecord = data[0] || {};
        localStorage.setItem('myCatalog',JSON.stringify(firstRecord));
    }
});
```

Otherwise, you would need to define a loop to handle each of the objects :-)

/John